# ThreadPoolExecutor with time.sleep(x) not executing all code

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have code similar to the following:

```
def dotheting(foo):
    output = foo + '\n'
    #complicated network IO type work
    output += 'blah\n'
    time.sleep(randrange(3))
    #complicated network IO type work
    output += 'blah2\n'
    print(output)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    executor.map(dothething, listofthings)
```

The output is like this:

```
foo1
blah
blah2

foo2
blah
foo3
blah
blah2



foo4
blah
blah2

foo5
blah
```

A random sample of threads end up missing 'blah2', some threads have new lines at the end, others don't and others have more than 1. My interpretation of python multithreading is that due to the Global Interpreter Lock it should only be able to run only 1 of the lines from dothething() at a time with the exception of some of my IO heavy network things and time.sleep(n), so what's happening here? How can I be missing blah2 outputs without having an exception raised?

Comment: My guess is that this is only a problem with concurrent printing. You may place a lock around the "print" call or send the output through a queue to a different thread that is only dedicated to call "print".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setup provides much cleaner, more predictable outcomes.

```
foos='''foo1\nfoo2\nfoo3'''.splitlines()

def dotheting(foo):
    output = foo + '\n'
    #complicated network IO type work
    output += 'blah\n'
    time.sleep(randrange(3))
    #complicated network IO type work
    output += 'blah2\n'
    return output

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    results = {executor.submit(dotheting,foo): foo for foo in foos}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        try:
            if(future.result() is not None):
                print(future.result())
        except Exception as exc:
            print('Exception on {}\n'.format(results[future]) + str(exc))
```